# unselect "Select all" if one option is not selected

Tags: javascript, html, angular

How should I unmark Select All checkbox if at least one option is unselected?
here's stackblitz code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f9jcac?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score -2):

Use `document.querySelectorAll("[type=checkbox]")` to grab all your checkboxes. Loop through and determine if one is unchecked, then un/check your "Select All" checkbox appropriately.